# Strcpy resulting in segmentation fault

Tags: c, strcpy

I'm not really sure why strcpy is resulting in a segmentation fault and was wondering if someone could explain to me why. I originally had `temp->data = name`  but that resulted in the Node value changing every time I changed the name array and was looking for a solution

```
typedef struct BST {
        char *data;
        struct BST *left;
        struct BST *right;
}node;



node *create(char name[]){
        node *temp;
        temp = (node *) malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
        strcpy(temp->data, name);
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        return temp;
}
```

Comment: show the structure `node`.

Comment: You aren't allocating enough space for the structure.  You need to allocate `sizeof(*temp)` (or `sizeof(node)`) and also the space for a string.  Since you're not using a flexible array member, you probably need two allocations; your one is certainly not enough.  And also `temp->data` is not initialized; it isn't pointing to any known memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the structure shown, you are allocating insufficient memory and copying to an uninitialized pointer.  Both are dangerous.

You need something more like:

```
node *create(char name[]){
    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
    if (temp == NULL)
        return NULL;
    temp->data = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
    if (temp->data == NULL)
    {
        free(temp);
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(temp->data, name);
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    // temp->generation = 0; // removed from revised question
    return temp;
}
```

Consider whether you can use [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) to allocate a copy (duplicate) of the string.  You'd still need to check that was successful.  Note that freeing a `node` involves two calls to `free()`.  Also, the calling code needs to check whether the node was successfully allocated.  However, this code imposes no error handling strategy on its caller — the calling code can do what it likes as long as it doesn't try to dereference a null pointer returned by the code.

Alternatively, you could use a C99 'flexible array member' like this:

```
typedef struct BST {
    struct BST *left;
    struct BST *right;
    char data[];
} node;


node *create(char name[]){
    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp) + strlen(name) + 1);
    if (temp == NULL)
        return NULL;
    strcpy(temp->data, name);
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    // temp->generation = 0; // removed from revised question
    return temp;
}
```

Now you can free the structure with a single `free()` call.  However, you can't create an array of these structures (though you could have an array of pointers to such structures).  In the context of a tree, that's unlikely to be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should malloc your node first with
    `temp = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));`
then malloc your new string with 
    `temp->data = (char *) malloc(strlen(name) + 1);`
then you can use
    `strcpy(temp->data, name);`
Also, you need to set your generation to whatever value you want.

Comment: Curious that this answer cast here `(node *) malloc(sizeof(node));`, but not here `malloc(strlen(name) + 1);`.  Recommend no casts.

Comment: Well, turned out that we don't have to cast it. So you can put the cast or not.  It should not affect the result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc - please read

Comment: Agreed that the casts can be present or absent, so a mixture doesn't affect the result.  However, programmers should be consistent, at least within a single piece of code (function, file, program, system — choose the size of your 'piece of code').  Inconsistency inside a single function smacks more of carelessness than careful thought.

Comment: Make those changes. But yes you detected it right..get UV.